# Drawing multiple Images to a tiff file in python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have same size of multiple images and I want to draw those images on a tiff file in such a way that there should be less than 5 elements in a row with some x distance (horizontally along the row) between its centres and y distance (vertically along the column) The images are stored in a folder, the program should read images and draw images on tiff file.

I found this as somewhat useful (and nearer to what i require) http://www.astrobetter.com/plotting-to-a-file-in-python/ But it is plotting a graph to file. I want to put images to my tiff file

How should I proceed?

Comment: Have a look at the copy and paste functions here: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html and update your post after you've had a go.

Comment: I am using RMagick in ruby, I want to do it in python. Yes, I tried with pillow. Does the composite function work the same as that of one in RMagick ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for tagging this with PIL (python-imaging-library) and actually using RMagick?

Comment: @carlosdc, Sorry but, I already implemented in RMAgick, but now I want it in PIL, I have to write some graph algos, for which I am not very comfortable in ruby, so I am preferring to switch to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you describe, I think. Here is the image, you can have many of them as long as they're all the same size, configure the values on the images list in the code to change this.

[image]

and this is the output of the program:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
import Image

images = ['image.jpg','image.jpg','image.jpg','image.jpg','image.jpg','image.jpg','image.jpg']

hsize = min(5,len(images))
vsize = (len(images)/5) + 1

print hsize,vsize

vspace = 10
hspace = 10

(h,w) = Image.open(images[0]).size

im = Image.new('RGB',((hsize*(h+hspace)),(vsize*(w+vspace)) ))

for i,filename in enumerate(images):
    imin = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
    xpos = i % hsize
    ypos = i / hsize
    print xpos,ypos
    im.paste(imin,(xpos*(h+hspace),ypos*(w+vspace)))
im.save('output.jpg')
```

Comment: awesome carlosdc  ... :) I want to save it in multiple format files, in tiff, pdf etc. I guess this does not work with pdf.